# Which operator is the fastest in Javascript to check whether 2 values are equal to 0?

Tags: javascript, optimization, bitwise-operators, micro-optimization

Which of the following is fastest and what is the justification for why?

(1) `if (x == 0 and y == 0)`

(2) `if ((x | y) == 0)`

(3) Other (Please mention. If any)

Comment: Knuth should know better.. ;-)

Comment: 1. is not valid javascript. 2. will fail for example `var x = 0, y =0.5; (x|y) == 0` - so "other" , for example `if (x===0 && y === 0)` - definitely will be fastest of the 3 as it's the only valid one

Comment: If you want to compare with the numeric `0` and not just any *falsy* value, you need to use `===`

Comment: I presume you are worried about this because this is in a part of your code which is executed ten million times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use [Strict Equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) if you want to check they are exactly the same, ie they're the same type too, just in case.

if (x=== 0 && y === 0)